# Не работает display: flex;

Tags: css3, html5, вёрстка

не работает display: flex;
Вот HTML код:

```
             <div class="verh_HEADER">
                <div class="verh_HEADER_flex_1">
                  <img src="img/Логотип№1.png" class="logo_img_verh">
                  <span class="Eccentrik_text_logo">Эксцентрик</span>
               </div>

               <div class="verh_HEADER_flex_2">  
                  <img src="img/map-marker-alt-solid 1.png" class="icon_mestopoloj_verh">
                  <span class="text_pochta_veth">eccentric.ukraine@gmail.com</span>
               </div>  

               <div class="verh_HEADER_flex_3">  
                  <img src="img/clock-solid 1.png" class="icon_vrema_robotu_verh">
                  <button class="button_Podat_zaavku_verh"></button>
               </div>
             </div>
         </header>

Вот CSS код:
.HEADER{
    display: block;
}
.verh_HEADER{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
.verh_HEADER_flex_1{
    display: inline-block;
}
.verh_HEADER_flex_2{
    display: inline-block;
}
.verh_HEADER_flex_3{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

После того как я применил этот код ничего не изменилось, тоже самое что и когда display: block;

Comment: Что должно было измениться? ответив на мой комментарий, думаю вы лучше поймете что хотите

Answer (score 0):

```
 <style>
    .HEADER{
        display: block;
    }
    .verh_HEADER{
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .verh_HEADER_flex_1{
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .verh_HEADER_flex_2{
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .verh_HEADER_flex_3{
        display: inline-block;
    }

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Работает же

```css
.HEADER{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}
.verh_HEADER{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
.verh_HEADER_flex_1{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 15px;
}
.verh_HEADER_flex_2{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 15px;
}
.verh_HEADER_flex_3{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="verh_HEADER">
    <div class="verh_HEADER_flex_1">
      <img src="img/Логотип№1.png" class="logo_img_verh">
      <span class="Eccentrik_text_logo">Эксцентрик</span>
   </div>

   <div class="verh_HEADER_flex_2">  
      <img src="img/map-marker-alt-solid 1.png" class="icon_mestopoloj_verh">
      <span class="text_pochta_veth">eccentric.ukraine@gmail.com</span>
   </div>  

   <div class="verh_HEADER_flex_3">  
      <img src="img/clock-solid 1.png" class="icon_vrema_robotu_verh">
      <button class="button_Podat_zaavku_verh"></button>
   </div>
  </div>
  </header>
```